# Split data into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a df as

```
name category   dummy
USA   fx,ft,fe   1
INDIA fx         13
```

I need to convert this as

```
name category_fx categoty_ft category_fe  dummy 
USA  True         True        True         1
INDIA True        False       False        13
```

tried with series.explode() function but not getting this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) by column `category` with converting `0,1` to boolean by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
c = df.columns.difference(['category'], sort=False).tolist()
df = (df.set_index(c)['category']
        .str.get_dummies(',')
        .astype(bool)
        .add_prefix('category_')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    name  category_fe  category_ft  category_fx
0    USA         True         True         True
1  INDIA        False        False         True
```

EDIT: If need replace one column by multiple columns you can use:

```
df1 = (df['category']
        .str.get_dummies(',')
        .astype(bool)
        .add_prefix('category_'))

pos = df.columns.get_loc('category')
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :pos], df1, df.iloc[:, pos+1:]], axis=1)
print (df)
    name  category_fe  category_ft  category_fx  dummy
0    USA         True         True         True      1
1  INDIA        False        False         True     13
```

This solution is modifid for multiple columns:

```
print (df)
    name  category  dummy category1
0    USA  fx,ft,fe      1       a,f
1  INDIA        fx     13       s,a

cols = ['category','category1']

dfs = [(df[c].str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool).add_prefix(f'{c}_')) for c in cols]

df = pd.concat([df, *dfs], axis=1).drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
    name  dummy  category_fe  category_ft  category_fx  category1_a  \
0    USA      1         True         True         True         True   
1  INDIA     13        False        False         True         True   

   category1_f  category1_s  
0         True        False  
1        False         True
```

Comment: This is ignoring if there is other columns present in the df, can we have other columns present there as well..

Comment: @Kowsi - answer was edited.

Comment: @Kowsi - added ouput like need in question.

Comment: @Kowsi - so dont need `dummy` like last column?

Comment: what if there are other columns as category, like the same one i need to do for some other columns as well..

Comment: @Kowsi - second solution is changed for get_dummies for multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and [`astype(bool)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert your strings to new columns of booleans, then [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to change the column names, and finally [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns='category)
         .join(df['category']
              .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
              .astype(bool)
              .add_prefix('category_')
              )
      )
```

or, for modification of the original dataframe:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('category')
               .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
               .astype(bool)
               .add_prefix('category_'))
```

output:

```
    name  category_fe  category_ft  category_fx
0    USA         True         True         True
1  INDIA        False        False         True
```

###### generalization to more columns

assuming this input:

```
    name category1 category2  dummy
0    USA  fx,ft,fe     a,b,c      1
1  INDIA        fx         d     13
```

```
cats = df.filter(like='category').columns
cols = list(df.columns.difference(cats))
(df
 .set_index(cols)
 .stack()
 .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
 .groupby(level=cols).max().astype(bool)
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   dummy   name      a      b      c      d     fe     ft    fx
0      1    USA   True   True   True  False   True   True  True
1     13  INDIA  False  False  False   True  False  False  True
```

Comment: @Kowsi this works with any other column present

Comment: No, other columns are not showing.. Only name and new category columns are showing

Comment: in the second one it did and I edited the first one to handle it as you want (before, you needed to pass the list of columns to keep)

Comment: does it handle the other columns? like other columns with sep as , does it seperates into new one/

Comment: @Kowsi no, if you want to handle more columns you can first melt, then get_dummies, then pivot (or stack/unstack if using index). But this is a different question IMO.

Comment: It's difficult to generalize without knowing what you expect exactly, so better ask a follow-up question, but I provided an example as update.